# spring webflow: redirect in end-state depending on some input

Tags: spring-webflow

I have in my flow some input, i.e.

```
<input name="someInput" type="long" required="true"/>
```

and I'd like to redirect in an end-state to a location that depends on this input. I'm trying the following:

```
<end-state id="done" view="externalRedirect:contextRelative:/blahblah/${someInput}"/>
```

This is not working (the webflow does not replace ${someInput} with its value (it treats this as a standard string. Do you know how to do this properly?

Answer (score 5):

If you are speaking about Webflow 2.0 please try

```
<end-state id="done" view="externalRedirect:contextRelative:/blahblah/#{someInput}"/>
```